# Constructing an array with a key from an Input array

Tags: php

I have an array that has a list of PID, Email and Client in a comma delimited array. I was wondering if there's a way to parse the input array and generate a new array that has "Email" as the key and all unique PIDs for that email. Since the input array can have thousands of elements, I was wondering about the fastest approach.

```
Ex: Input Array (PID, Email, Client)
--------------------------------------
Array ( 
[0] => 10, abc@test.com,Gmail 
[1] => 11, def@test.com,Gmail
[2] => 12, abc@test.com,Gmail 
[3] => 13, def@test.com,Gmail
[4] => 14, xyz@test.com,Gmail 
[5] => 15, def@test.com,Gmail
)


Ex: Output Array (with Email as the key):
---------------------------------------------
Array (
[abc@test.com] => (
                   [0] => 10
               [1] => 12
          ),
[def@test.com] => (
               [0] => 11
               [1] => 13
               [2] => 15
          ),
[xyz@test.com] => (
               [0] => 14
          )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: foreach() then explode() on comma

Comment: Where did the comma-delimited array come from?  Are you calling `fgets()` on a CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// $input holds your initial array:
// $ouput is output...
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $arr) {
  // Explode the comma-delimited lines into 3 vars
  list($pid, $email, $client) = explode(",", $arr);
  // Initialize a new array for the Email key if it doesn't exist
  if (!isset($output[$email])) $output[$email] = array();
  // Append the PID to the Email key
  $output[$email][] = $pid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think of is this:

```
$outputArray = array();
foreach ($inputArray as $value)
{
    list($pid, $email) = explode(",", trim($value));
    $outputArray[$email][] = $pid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$emails = array();

foreach( $array as $item ){
    $data = explode( ",", $item );
    $id = trim( $data[0] );
    $email = trim( $data[1] );
    if ( !isset( $emails[ $email ] ){ $emails[ $email ] = array(); }
    array_push( $emails[ $email ], $id );
}
```